Moving tensor to cuda reduces precision
I am trying to move a tensor to cuda, but unfortunately, I am loosing precision. The first entry is 5.02e-5 which is converted to 0. Is there a work around?
vals = vals.to(torch.float64).to(device_of_t)


which is converted to 0 how are you checking it?

I’m printing it and dividing by it to check.

post the entire code to reproduce the problem

why precision matters in soft computing? If so, you can normalize your data into min of float 64 to max of float 64.
